# another representation of the zeta function of a curve over a finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, zeta-functions

Let $C$ be a non-singular curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$. 
Denote by $d$ the degree map from the group of divisors to $\mathbb{Z}$ 
and denote by $P$ the set of prime divisors w.r.t. to the function field.

> How the following implication works: 
>   $$Z(t,C)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{2g}{(1-\alpha_{i}t)}}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$$
>   $\Rightarrow exp(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}N_m \frac{t^m}{m})=exp(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(q^n + 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{2g}{a_{i}^n})\frac{t^n}{n})$

Should one take firstly the logarithmic derivative of $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{2g}{(1-\alpha_{i}t)}}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$ and then integrate this and apply $exp(\cdot)$?

(similarly works for $Z(t,C)=exp(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}N_m \frac{t^m}{m})$, where $N_m:=\sum_{P,d(P)|m}{d(P)}$ (see below))
I tried this approach, but I didn't get the desired.

Following is the context (see also [C. Moreno, curves over finite fields](http://books.google.ch/books?id=L8YnlDqV3MoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false/%22C.%20Moreno,%20Curves%20over%20finite%20fields%22%22)):

Let $C$ be a non-singular curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$. 
Denote by $d$ the degree map from the group of divisors to $\mathbb{Z}$ 
and denote by $P$ the set of prime divisors w.r.t. to the function field.

The zeta function of $C$ is defined by $Z(t,C):= \sum_{D} {t^{d(D)}} $, where the sum goes through all positive divisors.

One can show that

Theorem: $Z(t,C)=exp(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}N_m \frac{t^m}{m})$, where $N_m:=\sum_{P,d(P)|m}{d(P)}$

Comment: The author explains this step by saying "exponentiating the right hand-side". What does this exactly mean?